# What's this white stuff on my petunias?

Tags: identification, plant-health, diseases, pests, outdoor

[image]

Any idea what is happening here and how do I fix it???

Comment: It doesn't look like a disease or a pest to me. I'd say just wipe it off and see if it comes back. Have you been working around the plants?